# Selecting multiple configs from a Config Group in Hydra without using an explicit nesting level inside each of the configs

Tags: python-3.x, fb-hydra

The documentation in https://hydra.cc/docs/patterns/select_multiple_configs_from_config_group/ shows how to pick multiple configs from a Config Group and place them in a dictionary-like structure.

However, as mentioned in the very last paragraph there, *"example uses an explicit nesting level inside each of the configs to prevent them stepping over one another"*.
For my use-case, this would prove extremely cumbersome and I would like to avoid it at all costs if possible.

Is there a way to achieve a similar result without resorting to explicitly adding the level in the individual configs? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [defaults-list `@package` keyword](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/overriding_packages/#default-list-package-keywords) to achieve a similar result.

Let's assume you have changed the yaml files `server/site/fb.yaml` and `server/site/google.yaml` to not contain the "explicit nesting", so e.g. `server/site/fb.yaml` contains only the data `domain: facebook.com`.

You can achieve the same output as from the docs webpage using the following defaults list in server/apache.yaml`:

```yaml
# Option 1: With a non-overridable defaults list
defaults:
  - site/fb@site.fb
  - site/google@site.google
# Option 2: With an overridable defaults list
defaults:
  - site@site.fb: fb
  - site@site.google: google
```

Either option 1 or option 2 above produces this output:

```yaml
$ python my_app.py
server:
  site:
    fb:
      domain: facebook.com
    google:
      domain: google.com
  host: localhost
  port: 443
```

The `@package` directive here could be any compound key that you want. For example, using the following defaults list:

```yaml
# Option 1: With a non-overridable defaults list
defaults:
  - site/fb@foo
  - site/google@bar
# Option 2: With an overridable defaults list
defaults:
  - site@foo: fb
  - site@bar: google
```

We get this result:

```yaml
$ python my_app.py
server:
  foo:
    domain: facebook.com
  bar:
    domain: google.com
  host: localhost
  port: 443
```

Using option 2 (an overridable defaults list) means you can override the given default option using the CLI:

```yaml
$ python my_app.py server/site@server.foo=amazon
server:
  foo:
    domain: amazon.com
  bar:
    domain: google.com
  host: localhost
  port: 443
```

Comment: Amazing answer, thanks! I didn't know about option 1, looks very convenient! May I ask you, what is the difference between overridable and non-overridable defaults lists? Furthermore, is there a way to turn use the `@package` directive to specify elements of a list rather than key-values in a dictionary?

Comment: Internally, Hydra uses a different representation for the "overridable" and "non-overridable" forms, but the result of config composition is the same. Note that the overridable form only works for configs that are nested inside of a [config group](https://hydra.cc/docs/next/advanced/terminology/#config-group) (i.e. that are nested within a subdirectory, in the case of yaml files), whereas the non-overridable form works for configs that are at the same level of nesting as the config that contains the defaults list.

Comment: These two forms are supposed to cater to two different use-cases: the non-overridable form is for "including a config" and the overridable form is for "selecting an [option](https://hydra.cc/docs/next/advanced/terminology/#config-group-option) from a config group". With the "overridable" form, you can use the CLI to change the selected option (see the remark at the end of the answer above).

Comment: Currently Hydra has only limited support for composing lists (as opposed to dicts) via defaults. There are a few open github issues related to this topic (see e.g. https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/issues/1939). The current recommend workaround to achieve list composition via defaults is [detailed here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/issues/1939#issuecomment-1035395006).

Comment: (i finally got around to accept your excellent answer)